# Can't turn on iPhone, no backup and updating isn't successful. Is there anyway to retrieve the data?

Tags: itunes, backup, iphone

I am posting this for a friend.  For some reason the iPhone 5 suddenly won't turn on anymore.  When the power button is pressed the screen lights up, the apple logo shows and then it switches to another screen where the following url is shown: support.apple.com/iphone/restore, the iTunes logo and the a picture of a cable beneath.

What I have tried:

I have visited the url and followed the steps listed on the page, namely holding the power and home buttons for ten seconds, waiting and then trying to turn the phone on again.

I have connected to iTunes and tried to update the phone but this is unsuccessful and produces an error, with error code 26 which gives me this link here: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/ht201210.  I have followed the steps on this page as well.

What I think the problem is:

I believe the phone started to update but didn't have enough space and at some point the update failed midway and now the phone can't turn on.  I believe this is also the reason why it wont update via iTunes.  I do not know however as I wasn't present during this time and my friend isn't sure either, all she knows is it wont turn on anymore.

The phone has no backup and my friend would very much like to keep / retrieve the data on the phone somehow.  Therefore we have avoided trying a factory reset at this point.

We have taken it to a shop and they referred us to a specialist shop saying it would cost ~2000€ to decrypt and retrieve the data before performing a reset which is ridiculous.

Are there any steps or methods we could further try before resorting to a factory reset and losing the data or having to cough up all this money?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have tried to reset the phone yes?

Comment: @William I think OP stated they didn't want to reset the phone yet and risk losing all their data.

Comment: @fsb that is correct.

Comment: Is the phone jailbroken?

Comment: Whilst I can't say 100%, I am 99% certain it isn't.

Comment: @fsb aren't there soft and hard resets?  http://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/how-to-reset-the-iphone/

Comment: Yes, there are.  I think the OP is referring to a hard reset but I didn't know what you were referring to so I defaulted to 'hard reset' based on the question.

Comment: Yes, from the link you have posted, I have tried soft resetting to no avail.  Looking for any alternative to a hard reset and losing the data.

Comment: I am not surprised "~2000€ to decrypt and retrieve the data before performing a reset which is ridiculous."

Answer (score 2):

[Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com) or [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/en_download.html) may be able to help. It is evident that you are able to access the iPhone for a restore, so Disk Drill is likely the best choice.

Disk drill will create the best backup that it can with the files left unencrypted, and iFunbox will only be able to access whatever the phone can.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions unfortunately the phone doesn't seem to appear in either of the applications.  Tested that they are running fine by connecting my phone, which appears in both.

Comment: Is it possible to connect to the computer that it would normally be on, and try seeing if you can find cached files?

Comment: Maybe even opening iTunes on the original computer might help get a working copy backup

Comment: So I have tried connecting it to the laptop it normally connects to and connecting to iTunes and it produces the same results as when I connect it to my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt to retrieve the data yourself, or asking some friend who is able to do it.

Basically, you need to take out the motherboard, take out the flash drive chip using few repair tools, then you can use [Flash Memory Chip Programmer For iPhone](https://shop.rewa.tech/detail/64-bit-nand-flash-memory-chip-programmer-oem-new.html) (~$260), which can read and modify data of NAND flash memory chip (so you can backup the data into another drive). Of course, it's easier to say, than do, so good luck.

Here is the video demonstrating it: [Upgrade iPhone 6S 16GB Storage to 128GB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v5WDDZqhn2s).

Comment: Data on card will be encrypted.